# What is the return value of map::begin() for an empty map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I use something like this:

```
map<string, Data>::iterator it  = mymap->begin();
map<string, Data>::iterator end = mymap->end();

while (it != end) {
    // do stuff
    ++it;
}
```

I was just wondering if this would work even if the map is empty.
I couldn't find any information about the return of map::begin() if the map ist empty.

Comment: May I suggest to just create a small program to just test it?

Comment: `std::distance(begin, end)` will be zero.

Comment: Nice! I was not aware of this function.

Comment: @HWende `mymap.empty()` will also be `true`, I'd rather use that. Actually, I'd rather use an algorithm which will do the right thing.

Comment: @HWende also I would like to add that if a map is empty and you try to find any key in the map the find algorithm returns iterator to `end()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the map is empty, the `begin` and `end` iterators are equal, i.e. returns `mymap->end()`.

Comment: This is true, and you should always compare the iterator returned by `begin()` to `end()` before using it if the map may have been empty (note how your loop uses `while () ...` not `do ... while ()`, so it correctly tests before executing the controlled statement).  You ask what is the value - it could be anything providing it compares equal to `end()`, and incorporating the need for iterators to actual elements to differ... the Standard leaves the compiler/implementation to choose a suitable value.

Comment: I guess it is better to test `map::empty()` isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

You must not try to increment an iterator past end, 
OR DEREFERENCE an iterator to an empty map, that's why you must have if statements in you code to check the map and/or the iterator before you use it.

Comment: An `if` statement is not the only kind of conditional, the `while` used in the question will work just fine as well.

Comment: For empty map will `it == end`. So code will not enter while loop. It means you will not have problem with dereferencing iterator.